# Uploading a file in rMarkdown and call the file to generate Statistics Summary

Tags: shiny, rstudio, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I am new and trying to learn R, I have made an app where you can upload your file.csv, but I can not figure out how to call the data in order to generate summary, plot etc. I will appreciate your help to understand the systematic approach in how to proceed. The code is attached below. Thanks in advance.
The codes as follows:

````
---
title: "Data Visualization"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: scroll
    #storyboard: true
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}

library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)
library(formattable)
library(Hmisc)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
```

Sidebar {.sidebar}
=====================================================

```{r}
fileInput('file1', 'Choose a file to upload',
        accept = c(
          'text/csv',
          'text/comma-separated-values',
          'text/tab-separated-values',
          'text/plain',
          '.csv',
          '.tsv')
        )

```

Page 1
=========================================================

Column {data-width=350}
------------------------------------------------------------

### Dataset

```{r}
rv <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)

observe( {
  req(input$file1)

  inFile <- input$file1
  data2 <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  save(data2, file = "dataread.RData")

  rv$data <- data2
})

DT::renderDataTable({
  req(rv$data)
  rv$data
})
```

------------------------------------------------------------

### Data Summary

```{r}

summary(???)

#how to call the data, if PLOT, is it:

#plot(inFile$file) # In the code chunk it also called: 
#data2 <-     read.csv(inFile$datapath, #stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 
#if I write plot(data2),     it doesn't generate a plot, neither for summary.
```
````

Comment: I solve it, watching youtube videos. Thanks to all contributors.

Comment: Could you clarify what is the solution? I have the same issue now.

Comment: Taking from [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/uploading-a-file-in-rmarkdown-and-call-the-object-to-generate-statistics-summary/58247), this problem seems to have been solved (suggestion is to read up on materials [here](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-transfer.html#upload)).